# Last but one Char in vb.net String

Tags: vb.net, string

How do I find last but one character in a vbstring

for e.g. In the string V1245-12V0 I want to return V

Comment: Do you always want the second to last character or the last alpha-character in the string. This question is sort of vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the last alpha-character in a string you could use a LINQ query such as (C#):

```
var d = from c in myString.ToCharArray().Reverse()
                where Char.IsLetter(c)
                select c;
return d.First();
```

Answer (score 4):

**Don't use substring to get just one character**

```
Dim MyString As String = "V1245-12V0"
Dim MyChar As Char = MyString(MyString.Length - 2)
```

Comment: I agree. Can't see why 80% of the answers chose that method.

Comment: It's more flexible based on what the OP wants to do with that character later. The only reason I would use char in favour of string is unless I was absolutely 1000% certain that it would ALWAYS be a char that's required and someone won't come along and say "actually I now want 2 characters from the string" or I was desperately short of memory, such as an embedded device.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry it's been a while since I did VB so this may not be perfect (and is probably a mixture of C# and VB) but you get the idea:

```
Dim s = "V1245-12V0"
Dim lastButOneLetter = String.Empty

If s.Length > 1 Then
    'Can only get the last-but-one letter from a string that is minimum 2 characters
    lastButOneLetter = s.Substring(s.Length - 2, 1)
Else
    'do something if string is less than 2 characters
End If
```

EDIT: fixed to be compilable VB.NET code.

Comment: @Joel - why -1 for using substring?  It's much cleaner and more obvious than either Strings.GetChar... or mystring(...)

Comment: I thought the OP was pretty clear in asking for a "Char". Since I didn't downvote anyone else for using substring, I'll give you the up. It's worth remembering to do the length check.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim secondToLastChar As Char 
secondToLastChar = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.GetChar(mystring, mystring.Length - 2)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dhfexk4(VS.80).aspx

Or just remember that any string is an array of chars;

```
secondToLastChar = mystring(mystring.Length - 2)
```

Comment: @Joel Potter - then why don't you amend the question to specify not to use substring instead of downvoting everyone despite a vague question being asked! You have enough rep points to do that!

Comment: I didn't downvote everybody. I merely upvoted the best solution (Coehoorn's).

Answer (score 0):

string.Substring(string.Length - 2, 1);

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Substring` on the string s which contains 'V1245-12V0'

```
s.Substring(s.Length - 2, 1);
```

Comment: Mind me asking why this was downvoted? As others have mentioned this in similar form...to downvote and not leave a comment is deemed highly rude and ignorant which goes against the spirit of SO. How would you like it if I downvoted your answer, not leave a comment and you did not know what was the reason...?

Comment: It was probably from Joel Potter who disagrees with using substring.  If you notice every answer that used Substring has been downvoted even though it was a perfectly adequate solution based on the information we were given.  A downvote IMO is for an answer that doesn't solve the original problem, not because of somebody's personal preference.

Comment: Nope. Wasn't me. Though your answer is in C# so that might have been it.

Answer (score 0):

Was it difficult?

```
dim mychar as string
dim yourstring as string
yourstring="V1245-12V0"
mychar=yourstring.Substring(yourstring.Length - 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VB solution:

```
Dim text = "V1245-12V0"
Dim v = Left(Right(text, 2), 1)
```

You do *not* need to check the length of `text`, except for your semantics as to what you want to happen for empty (and `Nothing`) and single character strings.

Answer (score -1):

You can have your own functions like

```
Function Left(ByVal str as string, byval index as integer) As String

    Left=str.Substring(0,index);
End Function

Function Right(ByVal str as string, byval index as integer) As String

    Right=str.Substring(str.Length-index)
End Function
```

And use them to get what you need.