# Last but one character in a string in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Last but one Char in vb.net String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327307/last-but-one-char-in-vb-net-string)

How do I find the last but one character in a `String` in VB.NET.

E.g. I have:

```
Dim strTicket As String = "56789-091F0"
```

I want the value `"F"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim strTicket as string="56789-091F0"
Console.WriteLine(strTicket.Substring(strTicket.Length-2,1))
```

Check that your string is long enough before doing this tho!!

Answer (score 6):

Just select it as you would the next to last element of an array. I don't see the need for all the extra stuff.

```
Dim newChar As Char = strTicket(strTicket.Length - 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at `.Substring()` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx

Answer (score 0):

use the substring

```
      "56789-091F0".Substring(Len("56789-091F0")-2,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim s As String = "56789-091F0"
Dim c as Char = s(s.length - 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VB solution:

```
Left(Right(strTicket, 2), 1)
```

You do *not* need to check the length of `strTicket`, except for your semantics as to what you want to happen for empty (and `Nothing`) and single character strings.